# Конструктор принимающий тип LocalDate

Tags: java, localdate

Глупый вопрос наверное, но что-то не могу найти ответ.
У меня есть конструктор, в нем я хочу обозначить некоторые данные

```
public Main() {
        // В качестве образца добавляем некоторые данные
        contractData.add(new MainData("Test", 2011-11-10, 12-10-2011));
    }
```

Суть в том, что мне надо указать 3 типа данных, первый String, там все ясно, второй и третий тип LocalDate, и каким форматом я должен прописать в конструктор свою дату я не пойму, перебрал множество вариантом как своих, так и с гугла, подскажите формат ввода плиз.

Comment: LocalDate.of(2011,11,10) ?
т.е. new MainData("Test", LocalDate.of(2011,11,10), LocalDate.of(2011,11,12))

Comment: @RuslanP. да, после правки я понял, верно, спасибо
Могу принять как правильный ответ если перекинете сообщение